# Postman AWS Rest API -- as javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, postman, amazon-iam, restful-authentication

I made a simple IAM authenticated API that returns a random number.    [GET only]
Postman call works ok:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html?shortFooter=true

What is a simple way of getting the postman call to plain javascript
(No npm or webpack)

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axios` and `aws4` library in javascript to make api calls and send a signed request respectively.You need to authenticate the user via Cognito and retrieve temporary credentials (access key, secret key, and session token)

```js
let request = {
  host: 'myapi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://myapi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/foo/bar',
  path: '/foo/bar'
}

let signedRequest = aws4.sign(request,
  {
    // assumes user has authenticated and we have called
    // AWS.config.credentials.get to retrieve keys and
    // session tokens
    secretAccessKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
    sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken
  })

delete signedRequest.headers['Host']
delete signedRequest.headers['Content-Length']

let response = await axios(signedRequest)
```

[This](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/connect-to-api-gateway-with-iam-auth.html)  article might help you with the basic code to get temporary credentials from cognito and authenticate the user.

Comment: Thankyou for well thought out answer.    
To clarify, I am not seeking production advice in this case.
Just a single js function that simulates everything POSTMAN does to get a response for the **single IAM user's
secretAccessKey and accessKeyId**.  
I'm happy to have these credentials on the webpage  (its not public)  

If an intermediate token must to be used,    
Is it possible to generate it on this same page with an await code for example?  
Thanks for reading.